# User changed display name to match a diamond moderator, high-rep user in the community

Tags: discussion, moderation, user-accounts, users, display-names

I just saw this and, since I'm not accusing anyone, I'm curious if deliberately changing username to match the username of a diamond moderator is within the rules of Stack Exchange.

Comment: I also wondered that---the owner of the stolen name is aware.

Comment: I saw some tangential questions on meta https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188555/fake-moderator-using-a-moderator-icon & https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37942/policy-on-display-names Nothing too conclusive

Answer (score 15, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy

> **Identity Theft and Privacy.** Users that misleadingly appropriate the
> identity of another person are not permitted. Users may not post other
> people's personally identifying or confidential information, including
> but not limited to credit card numbers, Social Security Numbers, and
> driver's and other license numbers. You may not post information such
> as other people's passwords, usernames, phone numbers, addresses and
> e-mail addresses unless already publicly accessible on the Web.

Also, keep in mind that the discussed case is using username that is rather distinct (there are other "Tim's" on the site and I wouldn't bother if anyone used same username as me, I probably wasn't the first one as well). Moreover, it was about using username of one of the diamond moderators of this site, so this may lead to impersonating the moderator.

Comment: Do you take the last sentence to mean that I can't post your display name, even though it's publicly accessible?

Comment: @Firebug I added edit to clarify. I wouldn't go that far, but this case is pretty special.

Comment: I saw some discussions on impersonating Jon Skeet & Jeff Atwood (it seems like users got the hammer that time) in meta https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99914/what-are-the-rules-governing-display-names-and-avatars?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: i.e. matching your interpretation

Comment: I think this threads indicate we can do something, first contacting the user and asking they to change back, if not we could escalate this. This is a case of trolling, clearly.

Comment: I missed the details, perhaps fortunately, as that means the question can be answered as  a matter of principle. The benign interpretation is that this was a prank or arose from a particular sense of humour, but it is not acceptable and should always be reversed, ideally by persuasion rather than force or censure.